# Making non-bootstrap nav bar expand after menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a bit of trouble making my nav menu appear from clicking the nav menu icon.

**HTML**

```
nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-header">
        <a href="#"><span style="font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive; font-size: 1.4em;">Testy Testy Web</span></a>
        <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {width: 100%; position: fixed; text-align: left; background-color: #404040; z-index: 999;}
nav ul li {display: inline;}
nav a {text-decoration: none; float: left; color: white; padding: 1em; line-height: 100%;}
nav a:hover {background-color: #1AA2D4;}
.nav-header a {display: inline-block;}
#toggle {float: right; display: none;}

@media (max-width: 592px) {
    .splash p {font-size: 1em;}
    .splash h1 {font-size: 8em;}
    nav {width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; text-align: left; background-color: #404040; z-index: 999;}
    nav ul li {display: block; float: left; clear: left; width: 100%; clear: bottom;}
    nav ul {width: 100%;}
    nav a {text-decoration: none; float: left; color: white; padding: 1em; line-height: 100%;}
    #toggle {float: right; display: block;}
    #menu {display: none;}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#toggle').click(function(){
        $('#menu').css('display', 'visible');
    });

});
```

Basically, I have it so that the nav links are hidden when displayed on smaller screens, however I am struggling to figure out how to get jQuery to make it visible when you click the toggle icon. I know this is a standard thing in Bootstrap, but the website I am building is not using a framework.

Is anyone able to let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  `$('#menu').show()`?

Comment: $('#menu').css('display', 'visible'); -- there is no visible value for display -- check here -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp -- you can do -- $('#menu').css('display', 'none'); -- to hide -- $('#menu').css('display', ''); -- to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display` property gets `block`, `inline`, `inline-block` and `none` values. To show menu, you should change this line:

```
$('#menu').css('display', 'visible');
```

To :

```
$('#menu').css('display', 'block');
```

Also you can use `toggle` in order to hide and show menu on each click :

```
$('#menu').toggle();
```

More info on using `toggle` : 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I have also tried this: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#toggle').onClick(function(){
  $('#menu').addClass('menu-visible');
 })
})

Comment: Seems to be working now. I think some of the problem was I had my custom script file listed before the jQuery CDN link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle class. Defined a new class "menu" which can be switched to show/ hide your menu. Cooked your code, you can replace your existing code with this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $("#menu").toggleClass("menu");
    });

});
```

```css
nav {width: 100%; position: fixed; text-align: left; background-color: #404040; z-index: 999;}
nav ul li {display: inline;}
nav a {text-decoration: none; float: left; color: white; padding: 1em; line-height: 100%;}
nav a:hover {background-color: #1AA2D4;}
.nav-header a {display: inline-block;}
#toggle {float: right; display: none;}


@media (max-width: 592px) {
    .splash p {font-size: 1em;}
    .splash h1 {font-size: 8em;}
    nav {width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; text-align: left; background-color: #404040; z-index: 999;}
    nav ul li {display: block; float: left; clear: left; width: 100%; clear: bottom;}
    nav ul {width: 100%;}
    nav a {text-decoration: none; float: left; color: white; padding: 1em; line-height: 100%;}
    #toggle {float: right; display: block;}
 #menu {display:none;}
  
    .menu {display:block!important;}
  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-header">
            <a href="#"><span style="font-family: 'Cabin Sketch', cursive; font-size: 1.4em;">Testy Testy Web</span></a>
            <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```